# Why is this local QMultiMap detaching when modified?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.9, shared-data, qmultimap

To give some background: in my project I put a debug breakpoint inside `QMap::detach_helper` because I wanted to see if I could spot any occurrences when implicitly shared QMaps were detaching due to an oversight e.g. using `find` when `constFind` could have been used. I didn't expect to hit it very often because mostly I am passing containers by const reference (as a side note there is apparently a tool called "clazy" to find such things).

I was then looking at some internal Qt v5.9.3 code that triggered the detach. The stacktrace shows that we are detaching from first line of `insertMulti` function which is called here on `contexts`:

```
// return true if accepted (consumed)
bool QGestureManager::filterEvent(QWidget *receiver, QEvent *event)
{
    QMap<Qt::GestureType, int> types;
    QMultiMap<QObject *, Qt::GestureType> contexts;
    QWidget *w = receiver;
    typedef QMap<Qt::GestureType, Qt::GestureFlags>::const_iterator ContextIterator;
    if (!w->d_func()->gestureContext.isEmpty()) {
        for(ContextIterator it = w->d_func()->gestureContext.constBegin(),
            e = w->d_func()->gestureContext.constEnd(); it != e; ++it) {
            types.insert(it.key(), 0);
            contexts.insertMulti(w, it.key());
        }
    }
    // find all gesture contexts for the widget tree
    w = w->isWindow() ? 0 : w->parentWidget();
    while (w)
    {
        for (ContextIterator it = w->d_func()->gestureContext.constBegin(),
             e = w->d_func()->gestureContext.constEnd(); it != e; ++it) {
            if (!(it.value() & Qt::DontStartGestureOnChildren)) {
                if (!types.contains(it.key())) {
                    types.insert(it.key(), 0);
                    contexts.insertMulti(w, it.key()); // Why does this trigger a detach?
                }
            }
        }
        if (w->isWindow())
            break;
        w = w->parentWidget();
    }
    return contexts.isEmpty() ? false : filterEventThroughContexts(contexts, event);
}
```

Why would local QMultiMap `contexts`-- which was never copied-- become implicitly shared and need to detach?

---

**My Theory**

This may not be relevant but size of `contexts` was zero at that line.

My guess is that the detach was caused by some kind of an optimization related to empty maps, but I'm not certain. I did notice that I get far fewer hits by putting the debug breakpoint inside the part of `QMap::detach_helper` which only executes for non-empty maps (that is, inside conditional `if (d->header.left)`)

Comment: Since insertMulti() modifies the container, detach() must be called to make sure no other instance is referencing this container.

Comment: @chehrlic of course, but `detach_helper` is only called when the container is implicitly shared. otherwise the "detach()" is a no-op and doesn't actually detach from anything.

Comment: `called when the container is implicitly shared. ` - Qt containers are by default implicit shared so detach() has to be called on every (possible) write operation.

Comment: Right, I already realize that detach() has to be called on every possible write. I am referring to `detach_helper()` which should only be called if it is really sharing data with another QMap instance. See qmap header: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qmap.h.html#_ZN4QMap6detachEv

Comment: I still don't see where detach_helper() is called except when the container is completely uninitialized (= the first time):
`QMultiMap<int, int> mm;
mm.insert(42, 43);  // detach_helper is called because the container needs to be initialized
mm.insert(43, 44);  // detach_helper is not called
`

Comment: @chehrlic thanks, I suspected something along those lines. If you write it up as an answer I'll give you credit for that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q(Multi)Map does not detach on every insert but only on the first one when the map is not yet initialized:

```
QMultiMap<int, int> mm;
mm.insert(42, 43);  // detach_helper is called because the container needs to be initialized
mm.insert(43, 44);  // detach_helper is not called
```